Connecting python with postgres
when i import the library psycopg2 in pycharm and run the code they give me the following error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINK\PycharmProjects\market\projet\projett.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "C:\Users\THINK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
    ...<10 lines>...
    )
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

i asked chatgpt but without results

Does this answer your question?

This question is similar to: I get this error - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found. what can I do about it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
